# Automate build process in xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I have a project with a large number of targets and to release my would have to go through each of them individually. Is there a way to write a script that would generate/compile all the .ipa files for me with one click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 4 you set up workspaces and schemes for the command line builds to run on.

Here is a link to a [blog post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/06/building-xcode-4-projects-from-the-command-line/) about it

Comment: how do I select a target? all the examples in that post use the active target.